# Comment github issues from Travis CI as TravisCIBot

Tags: github, travis-ci, github-api

In [this tutorial](https://damien.pobel.fr/post/github-api-from-travisci/) someone describes how to use the [GitHub REST API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) to create comments in pullrequests using GitHub's *personal access tokens*.
Finally, there appears a comment with your personal github account and avatar.
[In the example](https://github.com/dpobel/damien.pobel.fr/pull/62) one can see such a command with the text `Test it at [...]`.

Is there an option to comment as [traviscibot](https://github.com/traviscibot), such that this travis icon will show up instead? I want the reader to be able to distinguish which commands were made by Travis and which were made by a human.

**A possible work-around** would be to create a new GitHub account, name it `my-travis-1234567890`, add this account to the repository, create a *personal access token* for this account and use the latter. But is there a way without creating a new GitHub account?

Comment: No, you can't use your own access token to post a message as someone else. That would be a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That sounds obvious, but when you give travis your own personal access account to be able to deploy, it also commits with **Author: Deployment Bot (from Travis CI) <deploy@travis-ci.org>** and not with my github name. Also a travis icon shows up.

Comment: The commit *author* can be whatever you want, that's different to authorising to GitHub to push commits or post a message on a PR or issue.